# Append one large file to other large file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, large-files, fs, electron

I am working on an app using the electron framework(atom shell) and I am new to NodeJS. This downloads a large file as two(or more) pieces (>2GB each) by specifying byte range in the http get requests. After it is done I want to combine these two files. Till now I have been able to think of a solution such that open up both files and use fs.appendFile to append chunks of second file to first one. It seems to me that this will be a very slow process and also will block down nodejs. Is there any other efficient way. I am also willing to spawn a child process and use some other application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use streams in node.js to append one file onto another:

```
var fs = require('fs');

// open destination file for appending
var w = fs.createWriteStream("output.txt", {flags: 'a'});
// open source file for reading
var r = fs.createReadStream("input.txt");

w.on('close', function() {
    console.log("done writing");
});

r.pipe(w);
```

This will buffer the file, read it in chunks, write it in chunks, close both files, all done for you.

And, it's all done with asynchronous file I/O so it will allow other node.js activities to interleave (e.g. won't block node.js).

Comment: So this is the best way thanks for clarifying that this wouldn't block other activities.